# yiiGridView pagination is not working after first ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii

I have one page there are four gridviews in one page. When i click on any pagination page button (ex : 1,2,3,4,5,6) It takes me to that page without any problem [via ajax]. And replaces new html with old html. But now when i click on pagination button it just redirects to the url. It do not get loaded via ajax. Whole page gets refreshed.

It works when on click of one page button.If i initialize through console. Like when i put this and press enter in console then It will work for next page call. And for again i have to initialize via console to make it work for next page button press.

```
        $('#answer-grid').yiiGridView({'ajaxUpdate':['answer-grid'],'ajaxVar':'ajax','pagerClass':'pager','loadingClass':'grid-view-loading','filterClass':'filters','tableClass':'table table-responsive','selectableRows':1,'pageVar':'saved_card_id_page'});
```

I try to add script in ajax loaded copntent but it did not worked. Not event Alert got excuted.

```
<script type='application/javascript'>

    alert("This is also not getting executed. When it comes from ajax content.")

</script>
```

I know may be they strips down the all content except the gridview div. But the same thing works in other project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use afterAjaxUpdate parameter did this.

```
        'afterAjaxUpdate'=>"function(id, data){

             var newHtml = $('<div></div>');
             newHtml.append(data);

             var scriptExecute = newHtml.find('#scriptExecute');

             $('body').append(scriptExecute);

        }",
```

so now my script is getting executed as i append this to body. This was the scripts i append to the body as i can only do this way It is not proper way but it works..

```
<?php

$true = Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest;
if($true)
{

?>

<script type="application/javascript"  id="scriptExecute" >

        //alert("Execute this");

        jQuery('#share-grid').yiiGridView({'ajaxUpdate':['share-grid'],'ajaxVar':'ajax','pagerClass':'pager','loadingClass':'grid-view-loading','filterClass':'filters','tableClass':'table table-responsive','selectableRows':1,'pageVar':'CardShare_page','afterAjaxUpdate':function(id, data){

            var newHtml = $('<div></div>');
            newHtml.append(data);

            var scriptExecute = newHtml.find('#scriptExecute');


            $('body').append(scriptExecute);


        }});
        jQuery('#rate-grid').yiiGridView({'ajaxUpdate':['rate-grid'],'ajaxVar':'ajax','pagerClass':'pager','loadingClass':'grid-view-loading','filterClass':'filters','tableClass':'table table-responsive','selectableRows':1,'pageVar':'RatingLike_page','afterAjaxUpdate':function(id, data){

            var newHtml = $('<div></div>');
            newHtml.append(data);

            var scriptExecute = newHtml.find('#scriptExecute');

            $('body').append(scriptExecute);

        }});
        jQuery('#saved-card-grid').yiiGridView({'ajaxUpdate':['saved-card-grid'],'ajaxVar':'ajax','pagerClass':'pager','loadingClass':'grid-view-loading','filterClass':'filters','tableClass':'table table-responsive','selectableRows':1,'pageVar':'SavedCard_page','afterAjaxUpdate':function(id, data){

            var newHtml = $('<div></div>');
            newHtml.append(data);

            var scriptExecute = newHtml.find('#scriptExecute');

            $('body').append(scriptExecute);

        }});
        jQuery('#answer-grid').yiiGridView({'ajaxUpdate':['answer-grid'],'ajaxVar':'ajax','pagerClass':'pager','loadingClass':'grid-view-loading','filterClass':'filters','tableClass':'table table-responsive','selectableRows':1,'pageVar':'saved_card_id_page','afterAjaxUpdate':function(id, data){

            var newHtml = $('<div></div>');
            newHtml.append(data);

            var scriptExecute = newHtml.find('#scriptExecute');

            $('body').append(scriptExecute);

        }});

</script>
```